# Duplicate id, name using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have HTML code, I want to clone these field multiple time, with different id of

tag element, how to do? I tried to clone, but could not change the id. My HTML code is

```
<div class="adlthd">Number of Adults & child</div>
  <div id='formrepeat' class="ratediv">    
   <div class="Paxtbl" id="Paxtblid">
    <p></p><P>1</P><P>2</P><P>3</P><P>4</P><P>5</P><P>6</P><P>7</P><P>8</P><P>9</P>
     <div class="clear" id="snRates">
       <P>Season 1</P>
       <P><input type="text" class="inb4 itx validate[required,custom[number]]" name="1adult" id="1adultn1" onchange="convertToFloat(this)"></P>
       <P><input type="text" class="inb4 itx validate[required,custom[number]]" name="2adult" id="1adultn2" onchange="convertToFloat(this)"></P>
       <P><input type="text" class="inb4 itx validate[required,custom[number]]" name="3adult" id="1adultn3" onchange="convertToFloat(this)"></P>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>`
```

and my JavaScript is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mybutton').change(function(){
        var total = $(this).val();
        var newNum  = new Number(total + 1);
        div_rate =$('.ratediv').length;
        if(div_rate>total)
        {
          for(div_rate; total<div_rate;div_rate--)
          {
            $('#Paxtblid').remove();
          }
        }else{
          for(div_rate;div_rate<total;div_rate++)
        {
            $('#Paxtblid').clone().appendTo('#formrepeat');
        }
      }        
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: `$('#Paxtblid').clone().appendTo('#formrepeat');` There is no attempt here to change the is. Have you tried something like `$('#Paxtblid').clone().attr('id', 'Paxtblid_clone' + div_rate).appendTo('#formrepeat');` ?

Comment: @GolezTrol yes, I tried that, but it does not change id of <p> tag. I have to change only id of <p> tags. like 1adult1 1adult2, 1adult3 when I clone then id should be like 1adult11 or smthng else;

Comment: a quick note for you is id can't start with number, so `1adult1` is an invalid id (css selector can't style it based on such an invalid id). Although javascript and jQuery can still select it.

Comment: @KingKing: Please see [(this ref)](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html) It says: "*Previous versions of HTML placed greater restrictions on the content of ID values (for example, they did not permit ID values to begin with a number)*". HTML5 ***allows*** ID to begin with a number.

Comment: @abhitalks not sure about that, I meant about the working of ***CSS3***, not **HTML5**.

Comment: @KingKing: Yes. CSS spec does not allow it. But HTML5 spec does. IMO that doesn't mean they are *invalid* in the context of this question.

Comment: @abhitalks we better use the id so that it can be styled with CSS, I don't think using id starting with number has any advantage here. Also please note that my comment does not mean it relates to the OP's problem. It's just a quick note, I also said ***Although javascript and jQuery can still select it***, it's just a quick comment (some kind of off-topic note)

Comment: @KingKing: CSS can style such IDs (e.g. `[id='1x']`). However, my argument is not against CSS specs. It *is* valid in HTML5. Whether advantageous or not is another topic. This question is not tagged CSS, and there is no styling involved. My argument was *only* to clarify that it is *valid* in HTML5 and *invalid* in CSS. Nothing more, nothing less. Thanks for being patient with me. Cheers.

Comment: @abhitalks `[id='1x']` is not id selector, it's just attribute selector and it's a totally different kind of selector. The id selector has the most specificity and that's why using it is very helpful in some cases while attribute selector can't replace.

Answer (score 1):

How about cloning the required `div` to another hidden `div` and manipulating then `id` from there and the appending to the desired place.

```
<div id="form1"></div>
```

And in JavaScript :

```
    var number = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    $('#Paxtblid').clone().appendTo('#form1');
    $('#form1').find("input").each(function() {
        var randnumber=number++;
        var id="1adult"+randnumber;
        $(this).attr("id",id);
    });
    $('#form1').appendTo('#formrepeat');
    alert($('#form1').html());
    $('#form1').find("#Paxtblid").clone().appendTo('#formrepeat');
    $("#form1").html("");
```

And you could change the `id` as required.

Here is the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Zjz5r/3/).
This is what i can think , I couldn't get a direct solution. There maybe other possibility though.

OK I got a better solution for this. You could use the [:last Selector](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) , thus nullifying the necessity of hidden div as mentioned in the above solution :

```
  var number = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
    $('#Paxtblid').clone().appendTo('#formrepeat');
     $('#formrepeat .Paxtbl:last').find("input").each(function() {
        var randnumber=number++;
        var id="1adult"+randnumber;
        $(this).attr("id",id);
    });
```

And here is the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/V58AY/1/).

Comment: Ok i got a better solution to do it.